# dynamically creating the values for high charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create dynamic data for high charts,

i need to generate dynamic values in the x-axis

```
xAxis: {
 categories:['project1','project2']
   },
```

This is my for loop,

```
var project = [];
for(var i=0;i<project.name;i++){
   //new array
}
```

How do i create dynamic values in the x-axis.

Comment: Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6c8Af/

Comment: Ok I'll post it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an array variabile as parameter to the categories option of the chart.

Example:

```
// Original array
var categories1=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

// Copy and/or modifify the second array content and do some stuff
var categories2=[];
for(var i=0;i<categories1.length;i++){
   categories2.push(categories1[i]);
}

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: categories2 // reference categories to an array variabile
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/6c8Af/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a JSON data and after a long time able to resolve it. My requirement was to get JSON data and then I create a Map Object based on my data requirement. And dynamically create series for chart. I was able to create Series but nothing was coming in chart.

This was because the numeric digits has to be converted to Int . When I used parseInt, it worked for me.

Step 1: I get the JSON data and after manipulation it looks like this: `seriesData = {"O":series1}, {"A":Series2}, {"S":Series3}]`

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'demoGraph',
                type: 'column'
            },
           title: {
                text: 'Stacked column chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6],
                title: {
                    text: 'Severity'
                },
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Defects with Severity - 1,2,3,4,5,6'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -70,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                        this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                        'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{},{},{},{},{},{}],
        };

        for(var i in seriesData ){
            for(var j in seriesData [i]){
                options.series[i].name = j;
                options.series[i].data = seriesData [i][j];
                break;
            }
        } 

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Comment: But 1 drawback with this approach is number of curly braces. The no. of plot columns/data to required (like 3 columns for 1 point) is propotion to no. of curly braces. Anymis-match it throws error. So, keep the no. of braces in sync with data.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
var Series2 = [1,1,1,2,2,2];
var names=['O','A'];
var data1=Series2,seriesArray; //seriesArray is formed dynamically - array of int values

options.series = [{name: names, data: data1}]
```

This works properly